# Get sql rows from row

Tags: sql, go, copy, row, rows

How I can use one parse (Scan) method for `*sql.Rows` and `*sql.Row` in Go?

Parse (Scan) methods use one code for parse one row

```
...
row := r.stmOne.QueryRow(id)
rows, err := r.stmOther.Query(ids, params)
parseRow(row, &item)
for rows.Next(){
    parseRows(rows, &item)
}
...

func parseRows(row *sql.Rows, item *typeItem) error {
    err := row.Scan(....) /// same
}

func parseRow(row *sql.Row, item *typeItem) error {
    err := row.Scan(....) /// same
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate parse function when row.Scan does this already? What extra functionality do you want to add in parseRow/parseRows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
type RowScanner interface {
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}

func scanRowIntoItem(row RowScanner, item *typeItem) error {
    err := row.Scan(...)
}
```

```golang
row := r.stmOne.QueryRow(id)
rows, err := r.stmOther.Query(ids, params)
scanRowIntoItem(row, &item)
for rows.Next(){
    scanRowIntoItem(rows, &item)
}
```